# arduino json parser failing to parse a uri

Tags: json, arduino

HI I am trying to use the Json Library by Benoit Blanchon 2014-2016 from this URL https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson

I struggled at first as I had the second generation ethernet shield.  Got it going once I realised I needed the second ethernet library.

However I get the error message unable to parse json and I am unsure why, and how debug.

```
// Sample Arduino Json Web Client
// Downloads and parse http://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=53.440&lng=0.200&date=today
//
// Copyright Benoit Blanchon 2014-2016
// MIT License
//
// Arduino JSON library
// https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson
// If you like this project, please add a star!

#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

EthernetClient client;
const char* server =    "api.sunrise-sunset.org";                  // server's address
const char* resource =  "/json?lat=53.440&lng=0.200&date=today";   // http resource
const unsigned long BAUD_RATE = 9600;                              //     serial connection speed
const unsigned long HTTP_TIMEOUT = 10000;                          //       max respone time from server
const size_t MAX_CONTENT_SIZE = 512;                               // max size of the HTTP response

// The type of data that we want to extract from the page
struct UserData {
char sunrise[32];
char sunset[32];
};
// ARDUINO entry point #1: runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
// initSerial();
//  initEthernet();
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial.println("Serial ready");
 byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
 byte ip[] = { 192,168,0,202 };
 Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
 Serial.println("Ethernet ready");
 delay(1000);
 }

 // ARDUINO entry point #2: runs over and over again forever
 void loop() {
  if (connect(server)) {
   if (sendRequest(server, resource) && skipResponseHeaders()) {
   char response[MAX_CONTENT_SIZE];
    readReponseContent(response, sizeof(response));
    UserData userData;
  if (parseUserData(response, &userData)) {
    printUserData(&userData);
  }
}
disconnect();
}
wait();
}

// Initialize Serial port
void initSerial() {
Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
while (!Serial) {
 ;  // wait for serial port to initialize
}
Serial.println("Serial ready");
}

// Initialize Ethernet library
void initEthernet() {
byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
if (!Ethernet.begin(mac)) {
 Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet");
 return;
 }
Serial.println("Ethernet ready");
delay(1000);
}
// Open connection to the HTTP server
bool connect(const char* hostName) {
Serial.print("Connect to ");
Serial.println(hostName);
bool ok = client.connect(hostName, 80);
Serial.println(ok ? "Connected" : "Connection Failed!");
return ok;
}

// Send the HTTP GET request to the server
bool sendRequest(const char* host, const char* resource) {
Serial.print("GET ");
Serial.println(resource);
client.print("GET ");
client.print(resource);
client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
client.print("Host: ");
client.println(server);
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println();
return true;
}

// Skip HTTP headers so that we are at the beginning of the response's body
bool skipResponseHeaders() {
// HTTP headers end with an empty line
char endOfHeaders[] = "\r\n\r\n";
client.setTimeout(HTTP_TIMEOUT);
bool ok = client.find(endOfHeaders);

if (!ok) {
 Serial.println("No response or invalid response!");
}
return ok;
}
// Read the body of the response from the HTTP server
void readReponseContent(char* content, size_t maxSize) {
size_t length = client.readBytes(content, maxSize);
content[length] = 0;
Serial.println(content);
}
// Parse the JSON from the input string and extract the interesting values
// Here is the JSON we need to parse
//{
//  "results":{
//    "sunrise":"5:45:00 AM",
//    "sunset":"5:58:51 PM",
//    "solar_noon":"11:51:55 AM",
//    "day_length":"12:13:51",
//    "civil_twilight_begin":"5:10:15 AM",
//    "civil_twilight_end":"6:33:36 PM",
//    "nautical_twilight_begin":"4:28:54 AM",
//    "nautical_twilight_end":"7:14:57 PM",
//    "astronomical_twilight_begin":"3:45:29 AM",
//    "astronomical_twilight_end":"7:58:22 PM"
//  },
//  "status":"OK"
//}

bool parseUserData(char* content, struct UserData* userData) {
// Compute optimal size of the JSON buffer according to what we need to parse.
// This is only required if you use StaticJsonBuffer.
const size_t BUFFER_SIZE =
  JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(2)     // the root object has 2 elements
  + JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(10);   // the "result" object has 10 elements    
// Allocate a temporary memory pool on the stack
StaticJsonBuffer<BUFFER_SIZE> jsonBuffer;
// If the memory pool is too big for the stack, use this instead:
// DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;

JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(content);
 if (!root.success()) {
  Serial.println("JSON parsing failed!");
  return false;
 }
 // Here were copy the strings we're interested in
 strcpy(userData->sunrise, root["results"]["sunrise"]);
 strcpy(userData->sunset, root["results"]["sunset"]);
 // It's not mandatory to make a copy, you could just use the pointers
 // Since, they are pointing inside the "content" buffer, so you need to make
 // sure it's still in memory when you read the string
return true;
}
// Print the data extracted from the JSON
void printUserData(const struct UserData* userData) {
Serial.print("Name = ");
Serial.println(userData->sunrise);
Serial.print("Company = ");
Serial.println(userData->sunset);
}
// Close the connection with the HTTP server
void disconnect() {
Serial.println("Disconnect");
client.stop();
}
// Pause for a 1 minute
void wait() {
 Serial.println("Wait 60 seconds");
 delay(60000);
 }
```

Comment: sure that your json buffer is not overflowed ? What does Serial.println(content); in readReponseContent() exactly prints ?

Comment: the contents is strange it has 161 in front of the json and 0 afterwards, 161
{"results":{"sunrise":"5:59:04 AM","sunset":"5:39:19 PM","solar_noon":"11:49:11 AM","day_length":"11:40:15","civil_twilight_begin":"5:24:27 AM","civil_twilight_end":"6:13:56 PM","nautical_twilight_begin":"4:43:47 AM","nautical_twilight_end":"6:54:36 PM","astronomical_twilight_begin":"4:01:50 AM","astronomical_twilight_end":"7:36:32 PM"},"status":"OK"}
0
what is the best way to remove these?

Comment: Lets put a memset(response, 0, MAX_CONTENT_SIZE); after response definition.

Comment: sorry trying to figure this as I go, what part do you mean after response definition thanks.

Comment: I mean just put after the char response[MAX_CONTENT_SIZE];

Comment: Hi made that change and still getting this output:    161
{"results":{"sunrise":"6:00:50 AM","sunset":"5:36:54 PM","solar_noon":"11:48:52 AM","day_length":"11:36:04","civil_twilight_begin":"5:26:13 AM","civil_twilight_end":"6:11:31 PM","nautical_twilight_begin":"4:45:37 AM","nautical_twilight_end":"6:52:07 PM","astronomical_twilight_begin":"4:03:49 AM","astronomical_twilight_end":"7:33:55 PM"},"status":"OK"}
0

Comment: So after memset you have whole null array..so remove content[length] = 0;

Comment: I have made that change but it has made no difference same result as before

Answer (score 0):

There is a `161` before the JSON string because the server is using [Chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

It is a feature of the HTTP 1.1 specification and the only way to disable it is to use HTTP 1.0 in the request.

See:

- [New JsonHttpClient.ino](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/blob/master/examples/JsonHttpClient/JsonHttpClient.ino), which uses HTTP 1.0 and doesn't require the `response` buffer.
- [FAQ: Why parsing fails?](https://bblanchon.github.io/ArduinoJson/faq/why-parsing-fails/)